# Find the top of a column using xpath

Tags: xpath, nokogiri

Say a HTML table looks like this:

```
<tr> <td>     </td> <th> black </th> <th> white </th> </tr>
<tr> <th> 1st </th> <td> stuff </td> <td> stuff </td> </tr>
<tr> <th> 2nd </th> <td> earth </td> <td> stuff </td> </tr>
<tr> <th> 3rd </th> <td> stuff </td> <td> bingo </td> </tr>
```

Say also that I've found the table cell labelled "bingo" using XPath, perhaps with:

```
@cell = @table.xpath('.//td[contains(text(), "bingo")]')
```

(That's how you'd do it with Nokogiri.)

Then what's the canonical way of taking @cell and using it to find the header that tops the column that contains this cell?

That is, what's the canonical way of turning "bingo" into "white" and "earth" into "black"?

Comment: Note that this would be easier and also be semantically better markup if you used a `<thead>` around that first row. (Assuming you have control over the markup.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a normalizated table, this relative XPath expression from any `td` or `th` "cell":

```
preceding::*[
   self::td|self::th
][
   position() mod count(../*) = 0
][
   last()
]
```

Comment: I don't get how `position() mod count(../*) = 0` relates to finding the correct column.

Comment: @LumpN: For a R x C normalizated table, any cell has a distance of C x N with its counterparts. C would be count(../*) because it's a normalizated table. `position()` would be the distance **in the `preceding` axis**. There you have it.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro. What does normalizated mean?

Comment: @steven_noble: "Normalizated" in the sense that there is neither colspan nor rowspan.

Comment: @Alejandro: For this particular example the final clause -- [last()] -- is not needed. I am wondering if you have an example that shows when it would be needed?

Comment: @msorens: The `[last()]` predicate **is needed**. Otherwise you are relying on that your XPath engine returns node sets in document order and that your host language instruction takes only the first node in the node set.